# How to make Qt based user login application

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I had seen the answers of  the questions related to mine .But still I am not sure how to store the user information taken from Qt dialogue box on file and then encrypt it ,so that no one else can read it .The other thing is that how to match the password and user name which is pre-specified in the file I had encrypted earlier..

Answer (score 2):

if i understand you correctly, you just want to make an application that asks for authentication at application start-up, correct?

If that is the case, it is easy.  The basic steps are as follows.

Keep the username and password in a file (since Unix does not have a registry).  The file does not need to be encrypted at all (plain text will do).  You can use xml for this.  The data (text) in the xml file however that you write (the data... not the tags) should be written such that the strings that you write into the file are encrypted using a hash.  Just look up hashing in C++ (SHA, MD5, etc).  The decription/encrytion key can be hard coded in you application.

Then for the application logic.  The first thing you show the user is the login window.  If they fail loop it or exit application.  Basically only when correct authentication info is provided you kill the login windows and kick-start the main application window.

Comment: Altough the overall idea is correct there are no decryption keys for a hash function. A hash is one way - one can generate it, but not generate the original input from the hash. Every time the user tries to login you generate the hash again and then compares to the hash you originally stored. The password should also be "salted" - be appended with a given random string. The salt is stored together with the original hash. More information on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29.

Comment: Good point Vitor, when you are only concerned about comparing the strings for authentication you do not need to decrypt the string, you can just encrypt what user types using the same key(password). This is because if text is same and text is encrypted using the same key(password) then the encrypted version will be always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should take a look at the [QCA](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/) examples.

They have some nice examples of how-to use crypto in similar situations.

QCA is not standard in Qt but can be added on all platforms.